# How to get price without currency symbol?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, price, currency, grand-total

How can i echo grand total without the `$` symbol attached to it?

Am using the following code to display grand total

```
echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal())
```

right now it is displaying `$50.00` but i want to get only `50.00`, how can i do the same?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()
```

It will get you the grand total in this format `50.0000`. If you want only 2 decimals use this:

```
number_format(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(), 2);
```

Comment: where does this code go?  Inline or a specific file?

Comment: it goes where you need it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `directory/currency` model, this has a format function that will include standard localisation but it can also be customised. It has the following options:

1. price,
2. options (in this case NO_SYMBOL),
3. include container,
4. add brackets

So you can use it as follows and it will convert `15000.59863` into `15.000,60` for a German set-up, `15,000.60` for an English set-up and `15000,60` for a French set-up:

```
echo Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format(
    Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(),
    array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL),
    false
);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please Try This below one line code It's working for me.**

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format($_product->getFinalPrice(), array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), false); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$grandTotalOfProduct = $order->getData('grand_total');

$currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($order-> getOrderCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();

echo  $currencySymbol .number_format(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$grandTotalOfProduct = $order->getData('grand_total');

$currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($order-> getOrderCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();

echo  $currencySymbol .number_format(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(), 2);
```

Comment: Wont this display the price with the currency symbol? The question was how to remove it.