# Implementing Google Trusted Store with Magento- trim variable to 2 decimal places only

Tags: magento-1.9, googlestrustedstore

Below is my code for Google trusted Store. Currently it generates numeric values with four decimal places. For example, the value for this code: getGrandTotal(); ?>
it returns value in the format 25.0000 Is there a way it could be forced to return a value for 2 decimal places i.e 25.00

Thanks,

```
<?php
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
$address = $order->getShippingAddress();
$backorder = false; // some backorder logic
$download = false; // some download logic
$shipDate = new Zend_Date(); // some logic to determine ship date
?>


<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;">


    <span id="gts-o-id"><?php echo $orderId; ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-domain">www.example.com</span>
    <span id="gts-o-email"><?php echo htmlentities($customer->getEmail()); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-country"><?php echo htmlentities($address->getCountryId()); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-currency">USD</span>
    <span id="gts-o-total"><?php echo $order->getGrandTotal(); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-discounts">-<?php echo $order->getDiscountAmount(); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-shipping-total"><?php echo $order->getShippingAmount(); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-tax-total"><?php echo $order->getTaxAmount(); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-est-ship-date"><?php echo $shipDate->toString('yyyy-MM-dd'); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-has-preorder"><?php echo $backorder ? 'Y' : 'N'; ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-has-digital"><?php echo $download ? 'Y' : 'N'; ?></span>



    <?php foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item): ?>
        <span class="gts-item">
          <span class="gts-i-name"><?php echo htmlentities($item->getName()); ?></span>
          <span class="gts-i-price"><?php echo $item->getBasePrice(); ?></span>
          <span class="gts-i-quantity"><?php echo (int)$item->getQtyOrdered(); ?></span>
          <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country">US</span>
          <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language">en</span>
        </span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you figured this one out yet but you will need to round it down to 2 decimal points

```
<span id="gts-o-total"><?php echo (round($order->getGrandTotal(),2)); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this post : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10089/33619
It is exactly the same problem as you have. To quote @Marius answer :

> Try this:
>
> `Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()`
>
> It will get you the grand total in this format 50.0000. If you want
>   only 2 decimals use this:
>
> `number_format(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(),
>   2);`