# Magento 1.9: Change currency symbol as superscripted in whole magento site

Tags: magento-1.9, price, currency

I need to change currency symbol as super scripted to price value. I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688508/magento-move-currency-symbol-out-of-span-for-microformats) and [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10088/how-to-get-price-without-currency-symbol) but it changes formats on a particular pages or price instances.

I want to change in throughout my whole frontend site. Currently it shows as 
[image]

I want to display it as

[image]

Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing you can do is to use jQuery. Try with below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currencySymbol = "<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?>"
    jQuery(".price").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace(currencySymbol, '<sup>'+currencySymbol+'</sup>'));
    });
</script>
```